# iostat taking lot of time to return

Tags: solaris, troubleshooting, iostat, dtrace

I have a solaris 10 server with a lot of SAN disks (close to 1000 across all paths).  `iostat -En` takes close to 5 min to return.  Is there a way to figure out what is causing the delay? truss hasn't helped much.

Answer (score 2):

dtrace is definitely the tool you are looking for. you can use a relatively simple script to find out which syscall is exactly most time-consuming.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

syscall:::entry
/execname == "iostat"/
{
    self->ts = vtimestamp;
}

syscall:::return
/self->ts/
{
    @[probefunc] = sum(vtimestamp - self->ts);
    @["- all syscalls -"] = sum(vtimestamp - self->ts);
    self->ts = 0;
}

profile:::tick-1sec
/i++ >= 59/
{
    exit(0);
}
```

Plus, you can use the [DTrace Toolkit](http://www.brendangregg.com/dtracetoolkit.html), may be you will find something ready to use and more appropriate there.

Once you will determine the stucking syscall, you will be able to do more investigations around it.